# Empty title and screen in some pages using CasperJs

Tags: casperjs

I'm new to CasperJs, going through quickstart and this code works for me:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
casper.start('http://casperjs.org/', function() {
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
});
casper.thenOpen('http://phantomjs.org', function() {
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
});
casper.run();
```

But for certain webpages (https://www.seznam.cz, https://www.slever.cz) i got only empty title/screenshot/whatever

I execute script like this:
`casperjs --ignore-ssl-errors=true hello.js`

and with option --debug there is no clue what's wrong. I was trying to execute the script like this:
`casperjs --ignore-ssl-errors=true --ssl-protocol=any hello.js`
but with same result.

I'm using CasperJs 1.0.4 and PhantomJs 2.0 on Mac OS X.

Thanks for any advices

**EDIT**: I've downloaded beta version of casperjs and everything works fine now :)

Comment: Cannot reproduce with PhantomJS 2.0.0 and CasperJS from git on Windows.

Comment: I've tried this now on Linux and really - everything seems to be fine, so it must be bug in Mac version, I'm creating an issue, thanks :)

Comment: Please don't put answers into questions. You can roll back your edit and undelete your answer.

Comment: I've created new answer and Larry Schatzer wrote me that I should edit my question and write it there. You should make an arrangement how it is correct :)

Comment: Yes, I can see that. I've contacted Larry about this already on another answer. He made some questionable decisions lately. The need to upgrade some software is a valid answer.

Comment: Regarding your issue, I don't think you used PhantomJS 2. How did you install CasperJS? If it was through npm then CasperJS will use its internal PhantomJS which is much older.

Comment: First, I've installed both CasperJS 1.0.4 and PhantomJS 2.0 through Homebrew. After that, I've deleted it and installed CasperJS 1.1 through npm and it shows me that it needs PhantomJS < 2.0, so I've used PhantomJS 1.9.8.

Comment: Yes, you would need to install CasperJS from git to run PhantomJS 2, because currently there is no version that is capable/willing to do so.

Comment: ok, thanks :) Now everything works fine with CasperJS 1.1 beta and PhantomJS 1.9.8 so I'd better not to do any changes :) what about my deleted answer?

Comment: You can edit it into shape by describing what you did (which versions you installed and how) and then undelete it. You can also flag the comment by Larry as obsolete when you do that. You can also consider deleting the question, because it is quite a narrow subject. I'm not sure if it will be useful for future readers, because there is no way to know why the version change was necessary.